# Sending HTTP POST Request not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

not sure what is wrong:

```
//Send distance to ThingSpeak Server
NSString *distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.6f", currentDistance];
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api_key=H3MQFPAJ1IOK1WEI0W&field1=%@", distanceString];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.thingspeak.com/update"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

I'm just trying to send data to ThingSpeak server, but Xcode keeps throwing me errors during runtime. I'm fairly new to Xcode so I'm not sure exactly how to even read the error. It just says (lldb) in my console, and gives me a "Thread1, breakpoint 1.1":

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could you add detail of error?

Comment: What errors? Compile errors or runtime errors? What is the exact error message/messages, and on what line(s)?

Comment: Are you sure the API key and field1 value should be in a POST body? That syntax suggests that it's a query string that's part of the URL, not a message body.

Comment: updated my post a bit - let me know if there is anything else i should specifically look at - I'm not at all familiar with the debugger

Comment: Also I think it should be part of post body, at least thats how I got it working in Swift: http://pastebin.com/YXkwQ00U

Comment: What's the value of currentDistance, bro?

Comment: @Kevin: Can you tell me value of currentDistance? And have you tried it on Postman console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code and it worked:

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];
```

Also the breakpoint issue came from me accidentally adding a breakpoint when I was clicking around, which looks like a blue tab.